# Return combined result of tasks

Tags: asynchronous, rust

What I want to do is to execute asynchronous code in parallel, at the end await all tasks, and then add all the tasks results together into one collection, that I return.

I have the following method:

```
pub async fn get_projects(organizations: &Vec<Organization>) -> Vec<Project> {
    // Define collection to hold the projects.
    let mut result = Vec::new();
    // Create a collection of tasks to retrieve the projects.
    let mut tasks = Vec::new();
    // Create a new task for each organization.
    for organization in organizations.iter() {
        if !organization.is_pat_valid {
            // If the PAT for the organization is not valid, do not try to retrieve the projects for it.
            continue;
        }
        // Create a new task to retrieve the projects for the organization and store it.
        tasks.push(repositories::devops::get_projects(
            &organization.pat,
            &organization.name,
        ))
    }
    // Wait for all tasks to finish.
    let task_results = join_all(tasks).await;
    // Add the projects from the resolved tasks all to the result collection.
    for task_result in task_results.iter() {
        match task_result {
            Ok(projects) => result.extend(projects),
            Err(error) => println!("Error: {}", error),
        }
    }    
    return result;
}
```

## Problem

In the code section:

```
for task_result in task_results.iter() {
        match task_result {
            Ok(projects) => result.extend(projects),
            Err(error) => println!("Error: {}", error),
        }
    }
```

The `projects` I want to add to my result are from type &Project, not Project. If I change the `result`vec to `Vec<&Project>` I get the following error:

```
return result;
   |   ^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

## The question

I am absolutely new to Rust and I can not get how I return this result, since it seems like the results of all tasks are scoped to my function.

## Further information

The old, not so performant solution was implemented like this:

```rust
pub async fn get_projects(organizations: Vec<Organization>) -> Vec<Project> {
    let mut result: Vec<Project> = vec![];
    for organization in organizations.iter() {
        if (!organization.is_pat_valid) {
            continue;
        }
        let organization_projects =
            repositories::devops::get_projects(&organization.pat, &organization.name).await;
        match organization_projects {
            Ok(projects) => {
                result.extend(projects);
            }
            Err(error) => {
                println!("Error: {}", error);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This should be slower, because the asyn fn are not executed in parallel, but at least it worked.

Comment: Don't use `task_results.iter()`. That's where you are creating references.

Comment: By which, I mean rewrite the loop as just: `for task_result in task_results { ... }` (no `iter()`).